# debugging assembly code under gdb  | platform linux

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, recommendation-engine

I am new to debugging an assembly code under gdb.Therefore, I have some question;

- How can I run my assembly code (At virtual place ) without **actually** running it ?
- If it needs a value, how can I insert a value to see how it works for each case in switch statement?

  ex: I couldnot give example on assembly so I give it in c.

  ```
      scanf ( "%d",&y);
      while ( y ) {
           ...
           scanf( "%d", &x);
           switch ( x ) {

           case 1: ...
           case 2: ...
           case 3: ...
           }

       }
  ```
- If I need, how can I know what value is stored in a register ?
- How can I print out all display to my .txt file ? In other words, assume I have started my program and it runs with no break point and then I want print this display to .txt file. So, I can work on paper. As You know, paper is more powerful than computer :)

I know some of you will say "go and read gdb tutorial or man page".But, I could not find any good tutorials, with  example to explain how a command works. My brain  only works when my eyes see example :)

Platform is Linux 
Tool     is terminal/console

EDIT : Please give me a good website including good documentation, of course If you know

**Give me documentation of "how to [catch] fish", "not how to eat fish"**

Comment: feel free when you have a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I run my assembly code without actually running it ?*

Umm, err, what?!

*If it needs a value, how can I insert a value to see how it works for each case in switch statement?*

`set whatever = some expression`

Remember that registers have a $ sigil (e.g: `$eax`).

*If I need, how can I know what value is stored in a register ?*

For all registers:

```
info reg
```

For a specific register

```
info reg $eax
```

or

```
p $eax
```

or

```
p/x $eax
```

etc...

*How can I print out all display to my .txt file ? In other words, assume I have started my program and it runs with no break point and then I want print this display to .txt file. So, I can work on paper. As You know, paper is more powerful than computer :)*

```
set logging file foobar.out
set logging on
```

Comment: for umm, err, what?, Assume my program is doing its job in internet. However, I don't want, when I  run my program in gdb, it sends a message to server. I am trying to figure out where bug hides.I may run it many times. Try to understand me :)In other words, It may run in virtual place but I don't want that program send message to web.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this page: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka12961.html - it's for ARM assembler, most should fit for all assemblers. You can set the program counter to the desired instruction, put values into registers, view registers, view memory etc. Don't print it out, we're out of trees almost already.

Comment: +1 Although a link like: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_12.html#SEC91 would have been more specific to the OP's question